# Maybe-type of generic type parameter is incompatible with empty

Tags: flowtype

For every instantiation of `RemoteEntity`, I get an error on the type parameter that `This type is incompatible with empty`, referencing the `null` value for `value` in `newRemoteEntity`:

```
export type RemoteEntity<T: Identifiable> = {
  value: ?T;
  error: ?Error;
  // ...
}

export function newRemoteEntity(): RemoteEntity<*> {
  return {
    value: null, // error
    error: null, // OK
    // ...
  }
}
```

If I instead declare `value: ?Object`, these errors go away (but then I get other errors related to the loss of my type bound). Am I missing something or is this Flowtype bug/quirk?

Comment: what is the "Identifiable" Type? T is required to be "Identifiable", but newRemoteEntity casts it to null. I would guess this is the source of the error. Could you link to an example at flowtype.org/try?

Comment: I just pasted this example and defined my own `Identifiable` type and got no errors. There's something missing from this question.

Comment: I never can get `flowtype.org/try` to work; it's just three rippling dots in multiple browsers. `Identifiable` is just `type Identifiable = { id: string }`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround by making the fields optional (instead of required but with a maybe-type). However, it makes other code a little more complicated (since I have to check for nulls instead of just propagating them in object literals), so I would prefer having maybe-types work.

```
export type RemoteEntity<T: Identifiable> = {
  value?: T;
  error?: Error;
  pendingAction: ?string;
  // ...
}

export function newRemoteEntity(): RemoteEntity<*> {
  return {
    pendingAction: null,
    // ...
  }
}

export function requested<T: Identifiable>(
    state: RemoteEntity<T>, action: string, id?: string): RemoteEntity<T> {
  // Maybe-type version was more concise:
  // return {
  //   state: id && state.value && state.value.id === id ? state.value : null,
  //   error: null,
  //   pendingAction: action,
  //   // ...
  // }
  const result: RemoteEntity<T> = {
    pendingAction: action,
    // ...
  }
  if (id && state.value && state.value.id === id) {
    result.value = state.value
  }
  return result
}
```